# Children travel back in time to the Great Fire of London

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, childrens-novel

- brother and sister get caught in a rain storm (anywhere from 8-13 years old...)
- they travel back in time to right before Great Fire of London
- another rain storm brings them back
- no obvious reason (to my memory) of why they went back
- I think they helped people because they remembered reading about the great fire and knew of the devastation.
- I remember it as a great adventure..

Comment: This is quite brief can you remember anything else about this? When did you read it? What did they do back in time? Why were they sent back i.e. random coincidence or on purpose for some reason? How old were the children roughly? If you remember anything else about this you can [edit] the details into your question.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10282547-the-fire-king is a partial match, but I feel you would have mentioned the fairies.

Comment: [Escape from the Fire](https://cdn.macmillanyounglearners.com/readers-public/E4_ESCAPE_FROM_THE_FIRE_teacher_notes.pdf) is also a partial match, except that the boy and girl are cousins, and they use cell phones, not rain storms, to travel.

Comment: Unfortunately no to both :(

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat similar to [The Ghosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ghosts)  by Antonia Barber, which was made into the film [The Amazing Mr Blunden.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amazing_Mr._Blunden)  If correct, the rain is actually a mist, and it's a house fire, not the GFOL, and (spoiler) you forgot the ghost who is causing their time travel. But the similarities are a young brother and sister sent into the past to save people who died in a fire.

Comment: Unfortunately no :(